# scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP) not working in fragment in android studio

Tags: android, android-layout, scroll, fullscreen, android-scrollview

I have a scroll view parent in my fragment and one child view which is a constraint layout in the first child constraint layout I have many views so my question is how to scroll parent scroll view to last I have used all approaches no one works in my case I don't know why?
These articles I have [tried](https://stackoverflow.com)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/sv_home"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:layout_gravity="bottom"
android:paddingBottom="8.7dp"
tools:context=".ui.main.fragments.home.Home">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/langSelTolBar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.92">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/fromLangLO"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"

            android:layout_marginEnd="22.3dp"
            android:background="@drawable/spinner_background"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/swipeBtn"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_from_lang"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                android:maxWidth="80dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="English"
                android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                android:textColor="#000212"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/iv_from_lang_dropDown"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_from_lang_dropDown"
                android:layout_width="10dp"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/tv_from_lang"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/tv_from_lang"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/tv_from_lang"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_dropdown" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/swipeBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"

            android:padding="6dp"
            android:src="@drawable/switcher_icon"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/toLangLO"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="23dp"
            android:background="@drawable/spinner_background"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/swipeBtn"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_to_lang"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                android:maxWidth="80dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="Urdu"
                android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                android:textColor="#000212"

                android:textSize="15sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/lang_drop_down"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/lang_drop_down"
                android:layout_width="10dp"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_to_lang"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/tv_to_lang"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tv_to_lang"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_dropdown" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/inputLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="8.7dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="13.7dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_box_bg"
        android:minHeight="220dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/langSelTolBar">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/TextClearBtn"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="18dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_clear"
            app:tint="#77869d" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/idEdtSource"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="23dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="27dp"
            android:background="#f7f5f5"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:hint="@string/enter_text"
            android:importantForAutofill="no"
            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textMultiLine"
            android:maxLength="4000"
            android:minHeight="130dp"
            android:textColor="#d9000212"
            android:textColorHighlight="@color/fadeToolbarClr"
            android:textColorHint="#45454d"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/ic_custom_cursor"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:textSize="21.7sp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:theme="@style/cursorPointerColor1"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/inputFunLayout"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/inputFunLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/idEdtSource">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/pasteBtn"
                android:layout_width="23dp"
                android:layout_height="21dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_content_paste_copy" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/micBtn"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/speakOutBtn"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/pasteBtn"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_mic_icon" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/speakOutBtn"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/adjust"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/micBtn"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_speaker_icon" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/adjust"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/translateBtn"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/speakOutBtn"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/translateBtn"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginVertical="3dp"
                android:background="@drawable/spinner_background"
                android:backgroundTint="#5a8ffb"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".19"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_trans_btn_arrow"
                app:tint="@color/white_fade" />


        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/outPutLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="8.7dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="13.7dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_box_bg"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/toolBarClr"
        android:minHeight="190dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/inputLayout">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/translateTv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="23dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="23dp"
            android:background="@color/toolBarClr"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:minHeight="115dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textColorHighlight="@color/fadeToolbarClr"
            android:textColorHint="@color/white"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@color/toolBarClr"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:textSize="21.7sp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:theme="@style/cursorPointerColor2"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/outPutFunLayout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/translateTv">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/txtCopyBtn"
                android:layout_width="23dp"
                android:layout_height="21dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_txt_copy_ic"
                app:tint="@color/white" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/txtShareBtn"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/speakOutTr"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/txtCopyBtn"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_share_ic"
                app:tint="@color/white" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/speakOutTr"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView2"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/txtShareBtn"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_speaker_icon"
                app:tint="@color/white" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/speakOutTr"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".19" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

this is my whole layout code thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue the issue was that as I was doing visibility "gone" and visible in my view so as scroll down my last view lost focus so I just do outPutLO.requestfocus and my issue was resolved

```
private fun scrollDown(){
    binding?.svHome?.post { binding?.svHome?.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN)}
}
```

I used this method to full scroll